# Python implementation of netcat

Tags: python, python-2.x, networking

I'm trying to write a simple python script that acts like the nc program (netcat). I've got it working on OSX (the client that is) by testing against a netcat server, but I'm unsure about the way I've implemented it.

I'd appreciate it if anyone could give me some advice and/or let me know how you would implement it as I still consider myself a beginner. Maybe I should study more on threads and sockets before taking this task on?

By the way, I chose threads over polling for the reason that files in select don't work on Windows.

```
import sys
import socket
import select
import time
import threading

def _stdout_write(data):
    sys.stdout.write(data)
    sys.stdout.flush()

class NetSnake(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._close_connection = threading.Event()
        self._stdin_handler = threading.Thread(target=self._handle_stdin)
        self._stdin_handler.daemon = True

    def connect(self, rhost, rport):
        # handle connection refused...
        self._active_sock = socket.create_connection((rhost, rport))
        self._active_sock.setblocking(0)
        self._stdin_handler.start()
        self._handle_active_sock()

    def reverse(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.connect(*args, **kwargs)

    def _handle_stdin(self):
        while True:
            line = sys.stdin.readline()
            if not line:
                # eof
                break
            self._active_sock.sendall(line)
        # let other thread know that we want to close the connection
        # because eof has been reached.
        self._close_connection.set()

    def _handle_active_sock(self):
        # NOTE: select on windows may not be interrupted by Ctrl-C
        # if not, try time.sleep or event.wait instead.
        self._close_connection.clear()
        timeout = 0.1
        try:
            while not self._close_connection.is_set()
                ready = select.select([self._active_sock], [], [], timeout)
                if ready[0]:
                    data = self._active_sock.recv(4096)
                    if not data:
                        break
                    _stdout_write(data)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            _stdout_write('\n')
        finally:
            self._clean_up()

    def _clean_up(self):
        self._active_sock.close()
```

**Edit:** I've now realized that I can get rid of the event that signals
the main thread that EOF has been reached and just simply close the socket and handle select's error instead.

```
def _handle_stdin(self):
    try:
        while True:
            line = sys.stdin.readline()
            if not line:
                # eof
                break
            self._active_sock.sendall(line)
    finally:
        self._clean_up()


def _handle_active_sock(self):
    try:
        while True:
            ready = select.select([self._active_sock], [], [])
            if ready[0]:
                data = self._active_sock.recv(4096)
                if not data:
                    break
                _stdout_write(data)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        _stdout_write('\n')
    except select.error:
        pass
    finally:
        self._clean_up()
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](/q/123304/9357)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't know, sockets in Pythons can have an [associated timeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout). This will take care of the `setblocking(0)` + `select` part for you. Just catch the `socket.timeout` exception and decide what to do when the operation was canceled.

You can also set the timeout directly as the second argument to `create_connection`.

You can thus read from the socket using:

```
def print_recv(sock):
    while True:
        try:
            msg = sock.recv(4096)
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

Granted that the socket already has an associated timeout (or you can call `sock.settimeout(0.1)` as the first instruction of the function).

As a side note, this function does *not* account for shutdowns of the connexion from the server. If you want to handle this case, you can detect it when `recv` return an empty message. So the basic thing to add could be `if not msg: break` before `sys.stdout.write(msg)`.

Using this function as a thread, you can close the socket from the outside, somehow like you did in your second version, but the socket will, at some point, trigger an `OSError` on `sock.recv`. Catching that could be a bad idea, as it may hide more serious issues. Instead, I’d still rely on `threading.Event`:

```
def print_recv(sock, event):
    while not event.is_set():
        try:
            msg = sock.recv(4096)
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
        else:
            if not msg:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.stdout.flush()
```

So you’ll have to `event.set()` before `socket.close()` outside of the thread. Note, however, that due to scheduling randomness, the order of execution could be:

```
while not event.is_set(): # Thread-1
event.set()               # Main thread
sock.close()              # Main thread
    msg = sock.recv(4096) # Thread-1
```

and still lead to an `OSError`. It will not happen so often, but it will. So you may want to come up with better synchronization if you want a cleaner termination.

---

You’ll also note that I’m using a function instead of a method to print the messages from the server. It feels cleaner as it separate concerns. In fact, there is no real need to create a `class` here, appart from keeping around a bunch of related objects. But your setup + teardown logic had me wondering: this is a job for a context manager:

```
class NetcatManager(object):
    def __init__(self, rhost, rport):
        self._event = threading.Event()
        self._socket = socket.create_connection((rhost, rport))
        self._socket.settimeout(0.1)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._reading_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_recv, args=(self._socket, self._event))
        self._reading_thread.start()
        return self._socket

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._event.set()
        # Waiting for thread termination so there is no OSError when closing the socket
        self._reading_thread.join()
        self._socket.close()
```

Now all what is left to do is to send messages from `stdin` to the netcat server. Using the above context manager, it should look like the following:

```
def netcat_session(rhost, rport):
    with NetcatManager(rhost, rport) as netcat_socket:
        # Process stdin and use netcat_socket.send
```

And that’s it.

---

Now, on the topic of processing `stdin`, be aware that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (which is translated to `KeyboardInterrupt`) does not mean EOF: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> does. So catching the `KeyboardInterrupt` is meant to recover from an unusual termination of the program; it may or may not be what you want.

Putting everything together, we can come to:

```
import sys
import socket
import threading


class NetcatManager(object):
    def __init__(self, rhost, rport, timeout=0.1):
        self._event = threading.Event()
        self._socket = socket.create_connection((rhost, rport))
        self._socket.settimeout(timeout)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._reading_thread = threading.Thread(target=print_recv, args=(self._socket, self._event))
        self._reading_thread.start()
        return self._socket

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self._event.set()
        # Waiting for thread termination so there is no OSError when closing the socket
        self._reading_thread.join()
        self._socket.close()


def print_recv(sock, event):
    while not event.is_set():
        try:
            msg = sock.recv(4096)
        except socket.timeout:
            pass
        else:
            if not msg:
                break
            sys.stdout.write(msg)
            sys.stdout.flush()


def netcat_session(rhost, rport, input_file=sys.stdin):
    with NetcatManager(rhost, rport) as netcat_socket:
        # We do not iterate (for line in input_file) because stdin does not behave well in Python 2
        while True:
            line = input_file.readline()
            if not line:
                # EOF reached
                break
            netcat_socket.sendall(line)
    # Leave with the screen in a clean state
    print
```

Note the use of default values. You can now provide any file-like object as the third parameter of `netcat_session` and it will send instructions from there (so you can save a test session in a file and replay it over and over again using `with open('the_file.txt') as f: netcat_session('localhost', 5555, f)`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer :). I'm going to take your advice in and I've also tried your solution. I really like the context manager concept :).

Comment: Also, when trying your solution I killed the netcat server (nc -l 4444) with a keyboard interrupt, but the client seemed to hang on 'msg = sock.recv(4096)'

Comment: @heapexchange yes, when the connection is shut down, the client continuously `recv` empty messages. If you want to handle that, you can, for instance, add `if not msg: break` before `sys.stdout.write(msg)`.